# Datatables - RowsGroup throws error to other datatables

Tags: javascript, datatable, datatables

I have 3 Datatables initialized on one page. 3 with separate Id's and different data loaded in. When I use `rowsGroup` on one of the tables, it works fine. However with the other 2, they get stuck on "processing" and get an error `Maximum stack size exceeded`.

I have tried to add an "initComplete" to the end of each table so it knows that table is done with, but same issue. Here are my tables

```
let pestsTable;
    let diseasesTable;
    let weedsTable;

    //Table 1
    pestsTable = $('#pests_table').DataTable({
      "pageLength": 10,
      "processing": true,
      "ajax": {
        "url": '/assets/ajax/table_ajax_handler.php',
        "type": "POST",
        "data": {
          action: "getPestsForTable"
        }
      },
      "rowsGroup": [
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9 
      ],
      "columns": [{
          "data": "crop"
        },
        {
          "data": "pests"
        },
        {
          "data": "chemical"
        },
        {
          "data": "product"
        },
        {
          "data": "rate"
        },
        {
          "data": "max_no"
        },
        {
          "data": "hi"
        },
        {
          "data": "mrl"
        },
        {
          "data": "pcs_no"
        },
        {
          "data": "supplier"
        },
        {
          "data": "use_by_date"
        }
      ],
      "searchCols": [
        {
          "search": '<?= $crop ?>' || null
        }
      ],
      "columnDefs": [{
          "targets": [0],
          "visible": false,
          "searchable": true
        },
        {
          "targets": [1],
          "visible": true,
          "searchable": true
        }
      ],
      "order": [
        [2, "asc"]
      ],
      "initComplete": function(settings, json) {
        console.log("pests table complete");
      }
    });

    //Table 2
    diseasesTable = $('#diseases_table').DataTable({
      "pageLength": 10,
      "processing": true,
      "ajax": {
        "url": '/assets/ajax/table_ajax_handler.php',
        "type": "POST",
        "data": {
          action: "getDiseasesForTable"
        }
      },
      "rowsGroup": [
        1
      ],
      "columns": [{
          "data": "crop"
        },
        {
          "data": "diseases"
        },
        {
          "data": "chemical"
        },
        {
          "data": "product"
        },
        {
          "data": "rate"
        },
        {
          "data": "max_no"
        },
        {
          "data": "hi"
        },
        {
          "data": "mrl"
        },
        {
          "data": "pcs_no"
        },
        {
          "data": "supplier"
        },
        {
          "data": "use_by_date"
        }
      ],
      "searchCols": [
        {
          "search": '<?= $crop ?>' || null
        }
      ],
      "columnDefs": [{
          "targets": [0],
          "visible": false,
          "searchable": true
        },
        {
          "targets": [1],
          "visible": true,
          "searchable": true
        }
      ],
      "order": [
        [2, "asc"]
      ]
    });

    //Table 3
    weedsTable = $('#weeds_table').DataTable({
      "pageLength": 10,
      "processing": true,
      "ajax": {
        "url": '/assets/ajax/table_ajax_handler.php',
        "type": "POST",
        "data": {
          action: "getWeedsForTable"
        }
      },
      "columns": [{
          "data": "crop"
        },
        {
          "data": "weeds"
        },
        {
          "data": "chemical"
        },
        {
          "data": "product"
        },
        {
          "data": "rate"
        },
        {
          "data": "max_no"
        },
        {
          "data": "hi"
        },
        {
          "data": "mrl"
        },
        {
          "data": "pcs_no"
        },
        {
          "data": "supplier"
        },
        {
          "data": "use_by_date"
        }
      ],
      "searchCols": [
        {
          "search": '<?= $crop ?>' || null
        }
      ],
      "columnDefs": [{
          "targets": [0],
          "visible": false,
          "searchable": true
        },
        {
          "targets": [1],
          "visible": true,
          "searchable": true
        }
      ],
      "order": [
        [2, "asc"]
      ]
    });
```

Comment: Which version of DataTables are you using? I think [`rowsGroup`](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/29319/new-rowsgroup-plugin-merge-cells-vertically-rowspan) is an old third-party plug-in. If you are using DataTables v1.10+, you can take a look at the [`rowGroup`](https://datatables.net/extensions/rowgroup/) extension which I believe does the same thing as the older `rowsGroup` function - and maybe more.